# Code for Poll with unique voters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, unique-index

I have the following PHP/AJAX code for a poll kindly provided by w3schools.com :)
I'd like to allow users to vote only once (one vote per day or every 24 hours would be great), any idea?

### Javascript part

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="poll">
<h3>First Question?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br />
No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP part

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you have tried that is not working for you?

Comment: Probably want to insert the data into a database, as well. You could use PHP's `time()` function, send that to your database, then, when the user goes back to the page you run `time()` again, making sure there is more than a difference of 86400000 milliseconds. Or use a `$_SESSION`, but that can be removed by the user.

Comment: To detect uniqueness, you can use cookies (which can be removed as pointed out by PHPglue), or you could use their public IP. The issue with using IPs would be that public institutions such as libraries or schools would only be able to take poll once. A method would be allowing a one use access code to be entered as authentication to take the poll (which seems to be overkill because it's just a poll, not a survey).

Comment: Thanks, your replies have been really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}


function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      setCookie("voted",1,1)
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  if(!getCookie("voted")){
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    else{
    alert("you already voted!")
    }
}
</script>
```

there is a second variant  is  storing a voted IP in a DB or file.

Comment: also, I'm trying to put a "view results" link with the following code: <a onclick="getVote(this.value)" href="#poll">See Results</a> but it looks like it's still affected by the getVote function, which counts and sums the votes. any ideas on it?

Comment: change a function name like getResults(this.value) and implement essential functionality inside.